# Run button disabled IntelliJ - Maven project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I need some help.

I openned an existing project using IntelliJ, but I can't run it, because the run button is disabled.
All classes are red, but IDE doesn't say what's happening.
If I try to click in run button beside main method, nothing happens.
How can I solve this?
[image]

That's my configurations:
[image]

Comment: Well the debugger is green (will basically do the same thing without breakpoints), try that. Alternatively you could run/build it via maven, since that's how the project is set up.

Answer (score 0):

I ran mvn clean install, and that solved my problem.
Thank you all